# How to deselect items in listview (bound to List<myObject>) programmatically in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

It's Windows Phone 8.1 Universal.

I need to be able to select and deselect items in the listview.
I can't select/deselect a single item programmatically, but I can select all items in the listView with this method:

```
listView.SelectAll();
```

It would make sense to expect the exact opposite method built-in to deselect all, but there is none.

I can't use the following code because it's not bound to a list of ListItem object, but a custom object

```
        foreach (var item in listView.SelectedItems)
        {
            //item.IsSelected isn't available because it's a custom object
        }
```

How do I deselect all items in the listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If figured it. The following code deselects all items in the listView:

```
listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

Comment: Its is very much possible select/deselect single item in a listview.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post the code. So far I couldn't select/deselect single item programmatically in a listview

Answer (score 0):

The other way is listiew.SelectedIndex = -1;